# Sending JSON data via a POST request to https server

Tags: json, https, http-post, json-rpc, http-status-code-500

Please help, maybe anyone had experience of sending and receiving data through json via a POST request to the server?

There is programming interface (API) to it by passing json data you need to pass the parameters (method, id, params) and get the session ID (result).

Use the library: com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2

The problem is that at the stage of submitting the data (respIn = JSONRPC2Session.send(reqOut) the request falls off with the 500 error, but the server is available, it did not seem to understand that this is a post request, what is my mistake?

NetworkException:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://online.sbis.ru/auth/service/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.RawResponse.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.JSONRPC2Session.send(Unknown Source)
    at ru.documentum.sbis.integration.AuthLink.main(AuthLink.java:115)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ru.documentum.sbis.integration.AuthLink.main(AuthLink.java:129)
```

This is my code "main"

```
 package ru.documentum.sbis.integration;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.Proxy;

import com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.*;
import com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

import sun.rmi.runtime.Log;
import net.minidev.json.JSONAware;

import com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2ParseException;
import com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.ConnectionConfigurator;
import com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.RawResponse;
import com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.RawResponseInspector;
import com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2Request;
import com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2Notification;

public class AuthLink {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            URL ServerUrl = null;

        try
            {
                ServerUrl = new URL("https://online.sbis.ru/auth/service/");


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            }  

        // Create new JSON-RPC 2.0 client session
        JSONRPC2Session mySession = new JSONRPC2Session(ServerUrl);
        mySession.getOptions().setRequestContentType("application/json-rpc");
        mySession.getOptions().acceptCookies(true);
        mySession.getOptions().setAllowedResponseContentTypes(new String[]{"application/json-rpc"});
        mySession.getOptions().ignoreVersion(true);
        mySession.getOptions().parseNonStdAttributes(true);
        mySession.getOptions().trustAllCerts(true);

        mySession.setConnectionConfigurator(new BasicAuth());
        mySession.setRawResponseInspector(new MyInspector());

        String method = "СБИС.Аутентифицировать";
        Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        params.put("Логин", "sc6949");
        params.put("Пароль", "!653W74395w");
        String id = "0";

        System.out.println("Creating new request with properties :");
        System.out.println("\tmethod     : " + method);
        System.out.println("\tparams : " + params);
        System.out.println("\tid         : " + id + "\n\n");

        // Create a new JSON-RPC 2.0 request
        JSONRPC2Request reqOut = new JSONRPC2Request(method, params, id);

        // Serialise the request to a JSON-encoded string
        String json = reqOut.toString();        

        System.out.println("reqOut - json: Serialised request to JSON-encoded string :");
        System.out.println("\t" + json + "\n\n");

        JSONRPC2Request reqIn = null;

        try 
            {
                reqIn = JSONRPC2Request.parse(json);

            } catch (JSONRPC2ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
            }
        System.out.println("json - reqIn: Parsed request with properties :");
        System.out.println("\tmethod     : " + reqIn.getMethod());
        System.out.println("\tparams : " + reqIn.getNamedParams());
        System.out.println("\tid         : " + reqIn.getID() + "\n\n");

        String result = "result";

        System.out.println("Creating response with properties : ");
        System.out.println("\tresult : " + result);
        System.out.println("\tid     : " + reqIn.getID() + "\n\n"); // ID must be echoed back

        // Create response
        JSONRPC2Response respOut = new JSONRPC2Response(result, reqIn.getID());

        // Serialise response to JSON-encoded string
        json = respOut.toString();

        System.out.println("Serialised response to JSON-encoded string :");
        System.out.println("\t" + json + "\n\n");

        // Parse response string
        JSONRPC2Response respIn = null;

        try {
            respIn = mySession.send(reqOut);            

                } catch (  JSONRPC2SessionException e) {
            if (e.getCauseType() == JSONRPC2SessionException.NETWORK_EXCEPTION) {
                try {
                    throw e.getCause();
                } catch (Throwable e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
           else     if (e.getCauseType() == JSONRPC2SessionException.BAD_RESPONSE) {
              }
              try {
                throw respIn.getError();
            } catch (JSONRPC2Error e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

        // Check for success or error
        if (respIn.indicatesSuccess()) {
            System.out.println("getresult The request succeeded :");

            System.out.println("\tresult : " + respIn.getResult());
            System.out.println("\tid     : " + respIn.getID());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The request failed :");

            JSONRPC2Error err = respIn.getError();

            System.out.println("\terror.code    : " + err.getCode());
            System.out.println("\terror.message : " + err.getMessage());
            System.out.println("\terror.data    : " + err.getData());
        }
}}
```

This is my code of class "BasicAuth"

```
package ru.documentum.sbis.integration;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.ProtocolException;

import com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.ConnectionConfigurator;


public class BasicAuth implements ConnectionConfigurator {

    public void configure(HttpURLConnection conn) {

        conn.setRequestProperty("Host","online.sbis.ru");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "windows-1251");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "179");
        try {
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");

    }
}
```